# How can I save a string and use it in another class?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I want to use the value of deviceToken.Description in another class, in my case Game1.cs. I need to save deviceToken.Description in Program.cs somehow, but I don't know how. I created the variable MyToken to save the string, but I don't know how to access MyToken from another class.

How can save the value of deviceToken.Description so that I can use it in another class?

```
namespace Pushtest.iOS
{
[Register("AppDelegate")]
class Program : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    private static Game1 game;
    private static string MyToken = "";

    internal static void RunGame()
    {
        game = new Game1();
        game.Run();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }

    public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                               UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                               new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
        }

        RunGame();
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // Get current device token
        var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken))
        {
            DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
        }

        // Get previous device token
        var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

        // Has the token changed?
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
        {
            //TODO: Put your own logic here to notify your server that the device token has changed/been created!
        }

        MyToken = DeviceToken;

        // Save new device token
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Error registering push notifications", error.LocalizedDescription, null, "OK", null).Show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Program.MyToken`.

Comment: Thanks. It works with public static string MyToken = ""; and Program.MyToken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you saved the `DeviceToken` value in the Program class:

```
   NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
```

You can get the value in other class by:

```
   string deviceToken =  NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");
```

Refer:  [user-defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/user-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store a big amount of data you can just store it in properties, something like:

```
Application.Current.Properties["MyToken"] = $"{DeviceToken}";
```

And in another plase use it by:

```
var token= Application.Current.Properties["MyToken"].ToString();
```

Comment: It's not working. I get an error message in this line: Application.Current.Properties["MyToken"] = $"{DeviceToken}"; because .Current is null. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". What can I do?

Comment: Take a look if you trying to set this property from constructor of applycation, or from method in constructor and so on? If it is so - try to set this property after constractor finish.